# sudo tasksel remove lamp-server

Tags: server

What is the command I ran and now I have no ubuntu left...

When I which the computer on, the monitor comes on, it goes passed the grub screen, it does not show anything after that.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but it may work. I don't really know what you mean by "I have no Ubuntu left" and how much of Ubuntu you are missing.

Take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel

The first thing i would try is to run...

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^

It may help. If not, let us know.

Comment: I had to login to recovery mode from grub, drop down to the command line with networking and ran tasksel and selected ubuntu-desktop.  the desktop is back.  However, I don't have the plymouth boot screen anymore.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/574287), `tasksel` behaves badly when removing packages. It seems that it removes many packages that it shouldn't, which can leave the machine in an inconsistent state.

## Package Removal (A Better Way)

To remove something that you installed with `tasksel`, you need to mention the packages specifically. For example:

```
sudo aptitude remove apache2 apache2.2-common php5-common mysql-common
```

The theory is that removing these packages will cause the other parts of each system to also be removed. However, a manual search through Synaptic would still be beneficial.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/50115/13398) gives a much more detailed listing of what needs to be removed if you're trying to remove the LAMP stack.

## Recovery

To recover from `tasksel`'s over-zealous removals, you have to reinstall the affected packages. In some cases, installing ubuntu-desktop will do the trick:

```
sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop
```

To be more thorough, open up the Ubuntu Software Center and look through your removal history (see screenshot) to find the packages that were removed at the same time that you ran `tasksel remove`. You can then reinstall those packages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a common bug with ubuntu (see [#574287](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/574287)).

I was recently faced with the same issue. To address this, Once I was faced with the blank screen, I accessed an Auxiliary terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 (F1-F6) usually work for me, logged in and ran sudo tasksel again to recover from my mistake.