# How do I completely uninstall LAMP Server and start fresh?

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, lamp

**I am attempting to install LAMP server so I can work on PHP and MySQL databases locally on Ubuntu 16.04LTS.**

I got through a lot of the installation and then decided I wanted to start again (see below as to why). **How can I remove everything associated with LAMP server that I have just installed and start again?**

I went through the following steps when installing:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

and then

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

Upon going though these steps it asked me for a mysql password, which I (probably shouldn't have) left blank.

I then installed phpmyadmin, again leaving the password blank for root.

After installation of phpmyadmin I then had to use

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

And add this line:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Attempting to login to phpmyadmin threw up an error about removing the 'allownopasswords' or setting similar to that to allow me to enter with no pass.

At this point I decided to completely reinstall and use a password.

So I attempting to remove the packages I had used using some commands found here: [How do I remove the LAMP stack so I can start over?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50101/how-do-i-remove-the-lamp-stack-so-i-can-start-over) & [How do I remove the LAMP stack so I can start over?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50101/how-do-i-remove-the-lamp-stack-so-i-can-start-over)

I then reinstalled lamp-server, this time it showed no password entry and then I installed phpmyadmin.

Now when I goto localhost/phpmyadmin it just displays the config file, as if PHP is not installed.

I assume I am now missing some vital parts of the server.

**I want to completely start afresh and install LAMP from scratch, how can I do this?**

**It would also be useful to know what the different passwords are for mySQL that it requests on installation, is it just 1 root user and password?**

Thanks,

Comment: You can skip the "tasksel"  part if you use `sudo tasksel install lamp-server^`  (the ^ makes it connect to the task)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I remove everything already installed the first time and start again?

Comment: Related: [How do I uninstall MySQL completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640899/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql-completely)

Comment: See that one ^  and re-install will not fix your issue ;-)  I would ask about the problem you have and fix THAT. Learn from the problem.

Comment: I am looking for an answer on how to remove everything I have just installed. Surely if I have installed lamp-server this is made up of various packages that I can remove, but how do I know what they are? This is a question I find myself asking myself a lot when installing and wanting to remove software in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

My preference is using apt/apt-get rather than tasksel.

Many times seems to fail for me + disallow simple customizations.

Destroying an entire [LAMP Stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)) install can be a bit tricky.

You'll use **apt-get purge $package** to removed code + all config files.

Then use **dpkg -l | grep $package** to verify you've actually removed all traces of related packages.

[Installing Apache-2.4.28 + PHP-5.6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964165/how-to-install-php5-6-when-using-apache2-4-28-complile-from-source-on-ubuntu-16/965418#965418) covers how I install full lamp stacks for my hosting clients. Just change all occurrences of 5.6 to 7.1 to install latest PHP code.