# How do I check if a package is installed on my server?

Tags: server, package-management, system-installation, virtualization

I recently installed Ubuntu Server edition 13.10 (Saucy Salamander). But I have run into a bit of problem.

At the end of the installation, it asks about several extra packages whether you want them or not, like OpenSSH server and virtual machine host. Here's what I'm looking at:

[image: dialog offering packages]

Now, my problem is that I can't remember if I have checked the "virtual machine host" checkbox. How do I check if my server has the corresponding packages?

What packages come with the virtual machine host?

Comment: `$ apt-cache policy <package-name>`, e.g. `$  apt-cache policy dillo`

Answer (score 387, accepted):

Are you looking to know about all dpkg commands with options? Have a read from the below link.

[15 dpkg commands to Manage Debian based Linux Servers](https://www.linuxsysadmins.com/30-dpkg-commands-to-manage-debian-based-linux-servers/)

**To List all Installed Packages**

Here `less` is a simple text reader used to scroll through the list of packages in a new buffer that opens in the existing terminal window. The list will not be mixed with other terminal commands and output. Hit <kbd>q</kbd> to return to the terminal prompt. See `man less` for more info.

```
dpkg -l | less
```

To check whether a package is installed or not:

```
dpkg -l {package_name}
dpkg -l vlc
```

To check if the package is installed or not (for example, `vlc`). If installed, launch the package:

```
dpkg -l | grep vlc
```

Show the location where the package is installed. The `-S` (capital S) stands for "search"

```
sudo dpkg -S {package_name}
sudo dpkg -S skype
```

To use Grep to search:

```
dpkg -l | grep {keywords}
dpkg -l | grep pdf
```

Comment: What is the diference between this and _dpkg-query -l "packagename"_

Comment: Do not depend on the exit code of `dpkg -l packagename`, as it might return with a 0 exit code even if the package is not fully installed - see: https://github.com/bitrise-io/bitrise/issues/433

Comment: `dpkg -l | cut -d " " -f 3 | grep "^vlc"` to show all package names that start with `vlc`

Comment: FYI, this doesn't work for meta packages since they don't correlate directly to a dpkg.  Your response does answer the question as asked though.

Comment: @heypaleblue They are the same. From [manual page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/dpkg/dpkg.1.en.html#DESCRIPTION): "*`dpkg` can also be used as a front-end to dpkg-deb(1) and dpkg-query(1). The list of supported actions can be found later on in the ACTIONS section. If any such action is encountered `dpkg` just runs `dpkg-deb` or `dpkg-query` with the parameters given to it...*"

Comment: What the answer does not mention is: which output of `dpkg -l {package_name}` would inform that the package is installed?

Comment: @MarinosAn The first column of the `dpkg -l` output has to say `ii` for the package to be installed. If it says anything else (like `rc`) then it is not fully installed.

Comment: How can an answer that suggests using `dpkg -l` to check whether a package is installed get over 300 upvotes without explaining which part of the output actually tells the user whether a package is installed or not? Please annotate your answer to explain that the first column of `dpkg -l` has to say `ii` or otherwise the package is not installed.

Comment: @josch Thank you! Created an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1393059/622994) based on your feedback.

Answer (score 129):

`apt -qq list PACKAGE` can also be used for checking whether the PACKAGE is installed.

If installed it'll print something like (with `[installed]` at the end of the line):

```
$ apt -qq list awscli
awscli/stable,now 1.4.2-1 all [installed]
```

If not installed the output will be:

```
$ apt -qq list awscli
awscli/stable 1.4.2-1 all
```

Comment: You can put a star on the end of the package name for a wildcard.

Comment: You can also use the --installed option for that command to limit to matches which are actually installed.

Comment: What's the `-qq` for? It seems to work identically without it, and that option isn't in the manual `man apt`

Comment: @GabrielStaples It looks like the `apt list` command isn't yet fully documented. Some quick testing on 16.04 seems to indicate that `-q` is a synonym for `--quiet` option. The first `-q` prevents the word "Done" being printed. The second also prevents "Listing... " from being printed.

Comment: Even on Bionic, `apt list` still seems to be "WIP". Anyway for interactive use it does the job. I think in general `apt` family isn't meant for scripting, in which case you would still want `dpkg`.

Comment: CLI warning: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts

Answer (score 63):

Use `dpkg`

This command is the Debian package manager.

You can list all the installed packages with

```
dpkg -l
```

You can see details for a specific package with

```
dpkg -p packagename
```

And to learn if it is installed, use

```
dpkg -s packagename | grep Status
```

You can learn which package contains the software you want with

```
apt-cache search name*
```

In your case you should use this command to search the package name you want

```
apt-cache search virtual machine host
```

Comment: Also `apt-cache show <pkg_name>` to show detailed information about installed and installable versions of a package.

Answer (score 26):

**Simpler solution:**

There is now an `apt list` command that lists available packages, and the `--installed` command will show only installed packages.  You can also search for a specific package with

```
apt list <package>
```

Or to see only the matching *installed* packages

```
apt list <package> --installed
```

There are also the `--upgradeable` and `--all-versions` flags.

If you do not know the exact package name, you can use `apt search` followed by part of it to see a list of related packages.  This will allow you to use a partial name or regex term(s) to filter a list of available packages, but it does not have the nifty flags for filtering that `apt list` has.

Also see `man apt` for more information.

Comment: This has been [mentioned by Victor two years ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423355/how-do-i-check-if-a-package-is-installed-on-my-server/823630#823630).

Comment: Really is `apt list --installed | grep <package>`, the `--installed` part is mandatory

Comment: @ManuelJordan Yes and no.  Technically the `--installed` is needed to see _only_ installed packages (I've updated my post to make this clearer), but the `grep` is excessive since you can specify the package to the command directly.

Comment: Agree, 'grep' is a secondary filter .... would be nice indicate the explicit difference between `list` and `search` ...

Comment: @ManuelJordan Added :-)

Comment: Is interesting how these two options "search" and "list" are not merged in one command, something like `list --remote` (same as `search` to _search_ in the repositories and without matter if the `<package>` is complete or not) and `list --install` (to _search_ in the local computer) all the currently installed

Answer (score 21):

I've found a way to check for package installation with just `dpkg-query` command and no pipes.

I searched for such solution while writing a task for ansible playbook.

You can do something like this:

```
/usr/bin/dpkg-query --show --showformat='${db:Status-Status}\n' '<your package name>'
```

This is just one another way to do the thing.

Comment: pipes in ansible can be used with the `shell` module.

Comment: This is the most elegant way to check

Answer (score 9):

I am writing a new answer as [Tasksel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel) 'Task names' DO NOT show up in `dpkg` or `apt` queries. Meaning the other answers are incomplete (or wrong).

*"I can't remember If I have checked the 'virtual machine host' checkbox.."*

Check if there is an asterisk by the name after re-running `sudo tasksel` (or an ' **i** ' if running `tasksel --list-tasks`).

If you do not see this, then you **probably** do not have the 'tasksel [meta-package](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages)' installed.

---

*"..How do I check if my server has the corresponding packages?"*

If you want to find out what is installed under the Virtual Machine Host tasksel meta-package:

```
tasksel --list-tasks
```

(in your case `tasksel --list-tasks | grep virt` is enough)

This gives the proper task *name* and an indication as to whether it is installed.

In your case this tasksel name is `virt-host`.

---

*"What packages come with the virtual machine host?"*

From the last command, find the tasksel task name. This is needed for the next command:

```
tasksel --task-packages virt-host
```

This lists the individual Tasksel meta-package (denoted by appended '^') that make up the name. In your case it's `virt-host^`.

Once you find proper meta-name you can use apt:

```
 apt show virt-host^ | grep "Package:"
```

(or `apt-cache show` `...` if `apt show` doesn't work.)

This will show all packages making up the given meta package.

Then:

```
 dpkg -l {each individual pkg name listed above}
```

This will tell you if the individual package is installed/uninstalled (noted by 2nd letter: 'i' status means installed). Do this for all packages listed under the task/meta package.

***This should answer the original questions.***

Side note: `/usr/share/tasksel/descs/ubuntu-tasks.desc` also holds descriptions of Tasksel meta-packages. If you: `grep "virt" /usr/share/tasksel/descs/ubuntu-tasks.desc` it will show the proper APT meta-package name. (In your case this is `ubuntu-virt-server`). You can also use `apt` commands with this meta-name.

If you are wanting to remove tasksel packages, this gets into the weeds a bit. Please consult [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/88897/169878) or any number of other answers out there.

Please note that "meta" apt packages do not match Tasksel package names. Please consult the [Tasksel Community Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel) for more info.

Answer (score 7):

Use tasksel (`sudo apt-get install tasksel` if you don't already have it) and run `tasksel --list-tasks`.

tasksel will print out a list of the tasks, and there will be an `i` next to each task that is installed, and a `u` next to each task that is not installed.

If you wish to install the task, use `tasksel install <task>`. The name of the task you are looking for is `virt-host`.

The software selection items are called "tasks".

Comment: thanks for telling me the name of the task, that was one of my problems, wasn't sure which package to look for.

Answer (score 5):

**update:**

**Better** than parsing `dpkg` output, is to use `dpkg-query` output. The command below prints `installed` by itself if the package is installed:

```
dpkg-query --show --showformat='${db:Status-Status}\n' package-name
```

Again to suppress errors:

```
dpkg-query --show --showformat='${db:Status-Status}\n' package-name 2>/dev/null
```

**original:**

Based on feedback from [josch](https://askubuntu.com/users/394569/josch) in order for a package to be fully installed it should appear with a `ii` next to it. So a command to find out would be:

```
# if it prints the package, it is installed
dpkg -l package-name | grep -E '^ii\s'
```

Now in case it is not installed at all, dpkg can print an error, in case it was never installed in the past.

> dpkg-query: no packages found matching

We can filter appropriately to only get the information that we need.

The following prints `installed` if the package is installed, nothing otherwise.

```
( ( dpkg -l package-name 2>&1 ) | grep -E '^ii' > /dev/null ) && echo installed
```

Comment: "Now in case it is not installed at all, dpkg by default prints an error" this is still not true. `dpkg -l` lists packages that once were installed but are not installed now without an error. Also, if you start using this in a shell pipeline, `dpkg -l` is not the command you want to use. You want to use `dpkg-query --show --showformat='${db:Status-Status}\n'` or similar but *not* `dpkg -l` which produces output meant for human consumption and not scripts. The output format could change in the future and then your script breaks.

Comment: @josch "dpkg -l lists packages that once were installed but are not installed now without an error.": In that case I guess the line would not start with `ii` so `&& echo installed` which is based only on grep exit code (`false` when no match) will not be executed. In any case as you correctly pointed out `dpkg-query` is better so I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. One thing is still wrong though. You write that dpkg uses dpkg-query. This is not true. Why do you write down things if you don't know whether they are true or not?

Comment: @josch You are right. I misinterpreted the manpage which says: "dpkg **can also** be used as a front-end to dpkg-deb(1) and dpkg-query(1)". My bad, I updated.

Answer (score 4):

**Check if some packages are installed and install missing ones otherwise**

```
pkgs='hello certbot'
install=false
for pkg in $pkgs; do
  status="$(dpkg-query -W --showformat='${db:Status-Status}' "$pkg" 2>&1)"
  if [ ! $? = 0 ] || [ ! "$status" = installed ]; then
    install=true
    break
  fi
done
if "$install"; then
  sudo apt install $pkgs
fi
```

More info at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298066/check-if-an-apt-get-package-is-installed-and-then-install-it-if-its-not-on-linu/54239534#54239534

Similar technique previously mentioned at: https://askubuntu.com/a/1102572/52975

Comment: careful as this will not work if the package was previously installed then removed.

Comment: @js.mouret yes, updated.

Answer (score 3):

I created a little script with which you can automatically install from a list of packages or applications or simply check if they are already installed:

```
#!/bin/bash
apt -qq list YOUR_LIST_GOES_HERE | grep -v "installed" | awk -F/ '{print $1}' > /root/list.txt
packages=$(cat /root/list.txt)
grep -q '[^[:space:]]' < /root/list.txt
CHECK_LIST=$?
if [[ $CHECK_LIST -eq 1 ]]; then
echo "Your packages are already installed"
else
echo "Installing packages"
apt-get  install -y $packages
fi
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: `apt` shouldn’t be used in scripts, the command always says.

Answer (score 1):

Another (not necessarily better) way: see whether the field `APT-Manual-Installed` appears in `apt show <pkgname>`. If it is absent then the package isn't installed. Unfortunately it's not shown in `apt-cache show <pkgname>`.

As always, the `apt` is for interactive use and not recommended for scripting.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if I know or I want to confirm that mysql is installed use:

- `apt list --installed | grep mysql`

the `--installed` part is mandatory to confirm that is installed

Knowing that I don't have postgresql installed, so:

- `apt list --installed | grep postgresql`

returns empty/nothing

If I execute without `--installed`

- `apt list | grep postgresql`

it returns everything about postgresql package names and repository available

In global try `apt list --installed` vs `apt list` the latter is bigger than the former about the results returned, the difference is about of course what is installed or not, and what is available

Comment: While this is fine for informative version its return value isn't indicative

Answer (score 0):

The command (checking that python3-pip is installed):

```
dpkg --get-selections python3-pip
```

and the output (yes, is installed):

```
python3-pip                                     install
```

and with a missing package:

```
dpkg --get-selections some-missing-package
dpkg: no packages found matching some-missing-package
```

Answer (score -1):

In my scripts I simply use the `dpkg -s <pkgname> | grep installed` command then I test the exit code `$?`: if 0 means the package is installed otherwise if 1 the package isn't installed.

E.g.

```
> dpkg -s nano | grep installed
> echo $? # $? is 0, package "nano" is installed

> dpkg -s foobar | grep installed
> echo $? # $? is 1, package "foobar" is not installed
```

Comment: This will be wrong for packages that have the string `installed` anywhere in their description. For example try running `dpkg -s debsums | grep installed`.