# How to check if a virtual package is installed?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

In the following question there is a solution to checking for a package prior to installing it:

[How do I check if a package is installed on my server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423355/how-do-i-check-if-a-package-is-installed-on-my-server)

However, I have found that this does not work for [Virtual Packages](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s-virtual_pkg).

Is there a way to traverse the package name that apt-get automatically select and check for the correct one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [grep-status](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/grep-status.1.html) (package `dctrl-tools`, not installed by default) to find all installed packages providing some virtual package:

```
$ grep-status -FProvides,Package -sPackage,Provides,Status awk 
Package: mawk
Provides: awk
Status: install ok installed

Package: gawk
Provides: awk
Status: install ok installed
```

Comment: This sounds perfect, I will try it when I'm free and respond back. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Apt will not install a virtual package unless there is only one provider for it. If another package depends on a virtual package, it usually also names a real package as an alternative (i.e. build-essential depend on "libc6-dev | libc-dev" - the second being a virtual package).

Virtual packages are not installed, thus you cannot check their status. You can use `apt-cache showpkg <pkg-name>` to view which packages provide the virtual package, and then check whether any of these are installed.

Comment: See property `Reverse Provides` in the output.

Comment: In my case, this answer helped me. I installed a package that suggested another package. While I searched information for it, I got the *Can't select versions from package 'dovecot-common' as it is purely virtual* error. Using this answer, I was able to find which package name I had pass to `apt-cache show` (and install).

Answer (score 1):

@FlorianDiesch'answer looks interesting, but I want something without need for any software not installed by default.

I ended up using this:

```bsh
function check_packages_and_install_if_absent()
{
    for PACKAGENAME
    do
        if
            dpkg -l "$PACKAGENAME" | grep ^ii
        then
            echo "Package $PACKAGENAME is present"
            continue
        fi

        FOUND=""

        while read ACTUALPACKAGENAME
        do
            echo "$PACKAGENAME is a virtual package, that can be provided by $ACTUALPACKAGENAME"

            if
                dpkg -l "$ACTUALPACKAGENAME" | grep ^ii
            then
                echo "Actual package $ACTUALPACKAGENAME is present"
                FOUND=true
                break;
            fi

        done < <( apt-cache showpkg "${PACKAGENAME}" | sed -e '1,/^Reverse Provides: *$/ d' -e 's/ .*$//' | sort | uniq )

        # Using sed to print lines after match
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569032/sed-print-all-lines-after-match#answer-32569573

        if [[ "$FOUND" == "true" ]]
        then
            continue
        fi

        echo "Package $PACKAGENAME is absent, installing"
        sudo apt-get install -y "$PACKAGENAME"
    done
}
```

You can call it with a list of normal and/or virtual package names:

```bsh
function check_packages_and_install_if_absent foo bar baz
```

Answer (score -3):

You can query the database of installed packages for *packagename* with

```
dpkg -l packagename
```

And you can list all the files in *packagename* with

```
dpkg -L packagename
```

Read `man dpkg` for more information, like how to use wildcards.

Comment: As stated in the question this does not work for virtual packages.