# `g++` commands isn't working and APT is reporting `g++` is installed

Tags: compiling, gcc, g++

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I installed `g++` using

```
sudo apt install g++ 
sudo apt install build-essential
```

but when I want to check the version using this command

```
g++ --version
```

it showed me and also for gcc same the situation

```
Command 'g++' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install g++
```

Is there any way to check whether the g++ installed or not?

[image: you can see the photo]

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install g++` again. Please add any error messages to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1259617/edit).

Comment: the problem still continues even if I do sudo apt up

Comment: Did you remove some files manually? Try running `sudo apt install --reinstall gcc g++`. Retry your actions.

Comment: Yes. sudo apt install --reinstall gcc g++ solves my problem, many thanks Kulfy

Comment: @John Is this really a duplicate of [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories), then? As far as I can tell, the solution that actually worked for you--reinstalling the package--is not presented there and would not make sense there.

Answer (score 0):

### Steps you can try:

---

- Try `sudo apt update` before running `sudo apt install g++`.
- Restart the Terminal. *(If you connect via SSH, try **reconnecting**.)*
- Remove the `g++` with `sudo apt purge g++`, and reinstall it.

---

If you want to know if the package installed, check out
[this](https://askubuntu.com/a/423555/1103062) answer.

Comment: sudo apt install --reinstall gcc g++ solves my problem, many thanks Kulfy

Comment: @John Nice to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can check installed tools via this command :

```
sudo apt list --installed
```

In your case, "g++" is not installed.
Try updating the repositories before installing via these commands :

```
sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get install g++ -y
```